# If I reverse engineer a stack of items, what happens?

Tags: star-wars-the-old-republic

I had three Compact Medpacs in a stack. If I reverse engineer and right-click the whole stack is reverse engineered and I get some resources. I did this once by accident and wasn't paying attention to how much I got. Will get a proportional amount, or is it better to reverse engineer individually? How about my chances of learning a new schematic? Same if I reverse engineer a whole stack, or better if I do it individually?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You get the same random distribution of items as if you had Reverse Engineered (RE'd) each item individually.

After leveling cybertech, I can say there are times I wish its mods and armors *would* stack, just so I could RE them all at once.

The only reason I can see for *not* REing an entire stack would be if you were only trying to RE for a better recipe, and were planning on only REing until you unlocked it.

If you're planning on REing them all *anyway*, you may as well RE the full stack - for a stack of size 'n', it saves you 4 * (n-1) seconds!

Comment: So what if I am unconcerned about the money, but am looking for a better recipe: Are my chances of discovering a new schematic the same if I do them in a stack as if I do them individually?

Comment: @aslum Technically, the stack gives you a greater chance because you're REing more at once. Probability-wise, 5 REs rolling for a recipe are just 5 REs rolling for a recipe, regardless of whether you're doing the stack or one after the other.

Comment: Have they fixed this? It *was* bugged such that you only got mats as if you had RE'd one item, not a stacks worth.

Comment: @LessPop_MoreFizz Yes. I've gotten more mats from REing a stack than could possibly be obtained by REing a single item. Though I'll admit I haven't done any extensive testing.

Comment: it was fixed a few patches ago, I remember seeing the text about REing a stack